# Power LED blinks at first boot, but fine during second boot

Tags: power, power-supply, pi-3b+

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+. When I turn it on, it works fine but the red PWR LED keeps blinking. Everything else works fine, with no issues, but when I power it off and turn it on again, then it works fine—the red LED stays on and the Pi works fine.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a power supply that is just barely good enough. The APX803 gets triggered the first time, but not the second time. Probably a power supply that is just around the threshold.

> **Red power LED is blinking**
>
> **...**
>
> On model B+ (and presumably also the A+), the circuit has been improved to give a much more reliable
> warning of poor power quality. The red power LED is wired to an APX803
> supervisor[2] which kicks in when the 5V power supply drops below
> 4.63V[3]. If it does, the LED will blink. Check your connections, cable, and power supply.

[E-Linux R-Pi Troubleshooting](https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Red_power_LED_is_blinking)